# Embedding pyqtgraph into tab widget Pyqt

Tags: pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am bit new to Pyqt4 and pyqtgraph. I have tab widget with me and I want to add pyqtgraph into tab widget, so that this graph will be displayed inside (tab1) widget. Can any one tell me how can I do it? where should I add my pyqtgrapgh code in tab widget code. Corresponding code for tab widget and pyqtgraph is as follows.
code for tab widget :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(728, 507)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 691, 371))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 728, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "  PLOTS", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Code for pyqtgrapgh:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p6 = win.addPlot(title="My Plot")
curve = p6.plot(pen='r')
data = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))
ptr = 0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p6
    curve.setData(data[ptr%10])
    if ptr == 0:
        p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)  ## stop auto-scaling after the first data set is plotted
    ptr += 1
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(500)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

I have tried the way you have suggested me but now I am getting two windows popped up with none of them showing me the plots. I got one plotWidget in my tab Widget but how can I get rid of other plot window? Will you please tell me where I am exactly going wrong. The modified code which I am trying is as follows.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        global win,curve
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(728, 507)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 691, 371))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        ###
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(3, self.win, "plot")
        ###
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 728, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "  PLOTS", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p6 = win.addPlot(title="My Plot")
curve = p6.plot(pen='r')
data = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))
ptr = 0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p6
    curve.setData(data[ptr%10])
    if ptr == 0:
        p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)  ## stop auto-scaling after the first data set is plotted
    ptr += 1
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(500)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am also getting an error like - 
NameError: global name 'curve' is not defined
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Will you please tell me how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add `win` in your code directly to a tab page using [insertTab(index, win)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#insertTab). Optionally you can use `pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget` instead of `GraphicsWindow` (they're almost identical, but `GraphicsWindow` has minor changes that make it more convenient to use as a standalone widget)
2. Use Qt Designer to add a widget inside the tab and "promote" it to `GraphicsLayoutWidget` (see the [pg docs](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications) on this).

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but now I am getting two window popped with none of them showing plots. Now the modified code which I have tried is as follows

Answer (score 1):

So I have corrected some code, 
1. Firstly, Your pyqtgraph code should be inside Class Ui_MainWindow.
2. Secondly you have to add your plot widget to a layout to add it to your Tabwidget.
3. I personally prefer not to use global keyword.

I have corrected both the things your code now looks like this:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        global win,curve
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(728, 507)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
        #win.resize(1000,600)
        self.win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

        # Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

        self.p6 = self.win.addPlot(title="My Plot")
        self.curve = self.p6.plot(pen='r')
        self.data = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))
        self.ptr = 0
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 691, 371))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.win)
        self.tab.setLayout(self.layout1)
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        ###
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(3, self.win, "plot")
        ###
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 728, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        timer.start(500)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "plot_2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "  PLOTS", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def update(self):
        global curve, data, p6
        print "yo"
        self.curve.setData(self.data[self.ptr%10])
        if self.ptr == 0:
            self.p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)  ## stop auto-scaling after the first data set is plotted
            self.curve = self.p6.plot(pen='r')
        self.ptr += 1
        print "I am here"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        #QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```